# Ошибка в JS ! Помогите разобраться

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте была 1 форма , обрабатываемая в ajax , но понадобилось добавить вторую и думал что будет достаточно создать форму и дублировать скрипт от предыдущей c ajax изменив только id в скрипте , но не вышло. Какая ошибка ? что еще поменять ?
Консоль выдает "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

```js
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#formazakaza1').on('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $that = $(this),
        fData = $that.serialize();
      $.ajax({
        url: $that.attr('action'),
        type: $that.attr('method'),
        data: {
          form_data: fData
        },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(json) {
          if (json) {
            $that.replaceWith(json)
          }
        }
      })
    })
  });
</script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#formazakaza2').on('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $that = $(this),
        fData = $that.serialize();
      $.ajax({
        url: $that.attr('action'),
        type: $that.attr('method'),
        data: {
          form_data: fData
        },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(json) {
          if (json) {
            $that.replaceWith(json)
          }
        }
      })
    })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: jquery грузить пробовали?

Comment: у меня такой скрипт и форма с id formazakaza1 - идеально работали
В консоли "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: Скрипты работают на разных страницах?

Comment: Как я понимаю, это сообщение означает, что jquery не развернулось, а ваш код начал выполняться. вот он ни не находит $

Comment: @splash58 оказалось jquery подключалось ниже самого скрипта.
Но все равно есть какая то ошибка со скриптами.
Там где одна форма на страницах , отправляется благополучно и обработчик письмо высылает , там где 2 формы (2 скрипта) , форма фиксирует данные в БД , но обработчик письма не шлет.

Что во втором скрипте не так ? может там переменные какие то необходимо изменить ?

Comment: выведите в лог на сервере, что присылают формы, и сравните. внешне все норм

Comment: как подключен jQuery? убедитесь что бы 1 раз. и при вызове второй формы подключение не дублировалось, а так же что опять же он находиться выше других скриптов, в частности скрипта формы.